# Проблема с изменением размера кнопки в Qt Designer через styleSheet

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qss

Возникла проблема с изменением размера кнопки через `styleSheet`.

В `styleSheet` кнопки пишу:

```
    QPushButton{
        Width: 100px;
        Heigth: 35px;
    }
```

Но, результата нет. Кнопка не меняет размер. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QPushButton{
    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: знаю комментарий не по теме, но как вы сделали qt designer на русском?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров я ничего не делал, но я думаю, что если вы спросите это у сообщества, то вам подскажут.